# q-exponentials, Convolution and Multiplication

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convolution, exponential-sum, q-analogs

I am doing a modeling study using q-exponential distribution. I come to this question that are q-exponential distributions closed under convolution and multiplication operations? Let say X1 and X2 are independent q-exponential distributions, are X=X1+X2  and Y=X1*X2 also q-exponential?

I doubt this would happen, so I came across with two different methods to handle this, however, lacking a deep probability knowledge, I am not sure how much any of these approaches are valid or stable. Since I am going to perform the approximations in iterative manner and many times.

1- To approximate each of the q-exponentials by the respective Exponential distributions and perform the convolution operation on the Exponentials, next transform the resulting Exponential to a q-exponential distribution.

2- To take the first three moments of  X1 +X2 or X1*X2 and then determine the approximation q-exponetial according to these moments.

I would appreciate it if you can help me in this regards.

Comment: No I don't think $X_1+X_2$ and $X_1X_2$ are q-exponential. Why would you need it ?

Comment: Same. I need to use the convolution and multiplication operations in a network setting. However I know that q-exponential can be approximated by an Exponential distribution when q -->  1. That is why I come to the first method. Still stuck in ...

Comment: We can't help you if you don't explain what you want to do and why you are using this distribution.

Comment: Sorry, I thought my explanation was quite enough. I want to model arrival delay times of a group of transportation facilities under a transportation network. Each facility is assumed to have some delay distributed according to a q-exponential distribution. So to build my model I need to use convolution and multiplication operations. That is where the problem arise. Is it enough to catch the setting? Thanks

Comment: It explains the convolution, but I don't see why you need to look at $X_1X_2$. And the family of distributions $P(x)e^{-\lambda x}$ ($P$ a polynomial) should be adapted to what you need.

Comment: Well, for max(X1,X2) I need to perform multiplication operation. ..

Comment: Just wanted to add ... that family of polynomial Exponential distribution works when powers in polynomial terms are positive. Otherwise it becomes a burden. which happens in my case when I fit such a function to my data.